# the asterisk in print in python2.7 rise syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

in book Fluent Python, i find some codes in listcomp_speed.py, it runs well under python3.5, but it rises syntax error under python2.7 . the codes are:

```
def clock(label, cmd):
    res = timeit.repeat(cmd, setup=SETUP, number=TIMES)
    print(label, *('{:.3f}'.format(x) for x in res))
```

and the error is:

```
 def clock(label, cmd):
...     res = time.repeat(cmd, setup=SETUP, number=TIMES)
...     print(label, *('{:3.f}.formart(x) for x in res'))
File "<stdin>", line 3
print(label, *('{:3.f}.formart(x) for x in res'))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And it doesn't make sense to me,  as the asterisk in print is unpacking, and unpacking is support in print, as

    `print(*("1","2"))`

will work well.

and the same code run well in python3.5.

the book did not specify the environment of python.

Comment: I have read this book, and it *definitely* states that it is for Python 3 only. Here is an excerpt from the [Fluent Python page on O'Reilly's website](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do): *With this book, those Python programmers will thoroughly learn how to become proficient in **Python 3**.*.

Comment: @SethMMorton thanks,   i left the states out when reading preface.

Answer (score 2):

`print`changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2, it's a special statement that doesn't require parentheses. In Python 3, it's a function that requires parentheses but can also do more things - including taking arguments, like you showed here.

You can use Python 3-style `print` in Python 2 by writing

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your file.